# Build Cordova Apps in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We are implementing a cross platform app using Apache Cordova and Visual Studio 2015.
Trying to do continuous integration with Visual Studio Online builds and deploy the builds to our Azure Web App.

The issue is that the build definition in the Visual Studio online does not have the Cordova build and it considers just building the .sln file...

Any ideas how to build Cordova apps in VSO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to build Cordova Apps in Visual Studio Team Services (former Visual Studio Online) you will need to install this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-vsclient.cordova-extension

To build for different platform and the build step you can take a look at this document that will walk you through:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/cordova/cordova-build#install